# Link PHP file as PNG image? - Image is a variable based on server status

Tags: php, image, hyperlink, png, status

Here is my code, you can view an example of it by going to:
www.craftquake.com/statusChecker.php?site=MCnet

```
<?php

$getter = $_GET['site'];

if ($getter == 'ts3')
    { $site = test_port('ts3.craftquake.com',10011,4); }
if ($getter == 'MCquake')
    { $site = test_port('play.craftquake.com',25565,4); }
if ($getter == 'MCnet')
    { $site = test_port('minecraft.net',80,4); }

$teamspeak = test_port('ts3.craftquake.com',10011,4);

$online = '<img src="/online.png">';
$offline = '<img src="/offline.png">';
$unknown = '<span class="status-unknown" id="status-image">Unknown</span>';

function test_port($host,$port=80,$timeout=1)
{
        $fsock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
        if ( ! $fsock )
        {
                return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
                return TRUE;
        }
}

?>
##HEADER & CSS, ETC
<?php
if ($site == 1)
    { $status = $online;
    } else if ($site == 0) {
    $status = $offline;
    } else {
    $status = $unknown;
}

header('content-type: image/png');
readfile($status);
echo $status;
?>
```

I want to, in the footer of my page, link to this page to display the status. I was doing this with another site's script by linking their status of Minecraft.net's servers as the  and it worked perfectly, however I have no idea how they made that work. The images are PNG's, but if there is only one format that works, I can convert them.

I have tried the header(blablabla) function, but it doesn't seem to work...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your variables contain HTML instead of the path name to the image files:

```
$online = '<img src="/online.png">';
```

should be:

```
$online = 'online.png';
```

Create a unknown status image and put it in `$unknown` too.

Comment: Yes but the image should be displayed when the page is visited, correct? That's how the other site that I was using did it, at least.

If I change it to 'online.png', the image isn't displayed either when the page is visited or when it is linked on another page.

(and yeah, I have an unknown image, I just forgot to add it)

Answer (score 0):

An image should be a *seperate* request (so, put an `<img src="/yourimagescript.php">` in your html page, and in that *seperate* script output only the image, no html. You *could* embed (small) images with the `data:` protocol, but I **strongly** advise against it.